# How do I define AMPL like sets and parameters in Julia+JuMP?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I need to define some constant parameter in Julia+JuMP, similarly to what you do in AMPL when you define

```
set A := a0 a1 a2;

param p :=
a0 1
a1 5
a2 10 ;
```

How do I define something like `A` and `p` in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JuMP itself doesn't define a special syntax for index sets beyond what's available in Julia. So, for example, you can define

```
A = [:a0, :a1, :a2]
```

where `:a0` defines a symbol.

If you want to index a variable over this set, then the syntax is:

```
m = Model()
@variable(m, x[A])
```

JuMP also doesn't make a distinction between the data and the model in the same way as AMPL, so there's no real concept of a parameter. Instead, you just provide the data at the time when it's used. If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like

```
p = Dict(:a0 => 1, :a1 => 5, :a2 => 10)
@constraint(m, sum(p[i]*x[i] for i in A) <= 20)
```

This will add the constraint

```
x[a0] + 5 x[a1] + 10 x[a2] <= 20
```

Where we define `p` as a Julia dictionary. There's nothing specific to JuMP here, and really any julia expression can be provided as coefficient. One could just as easily say

```
@constraint(m, sum(foo(i)*x[i] for i in A) <= 20)
```

Where `foo` is an arbitrary Julia function that could perform a database lookup, compute digits of pi, etc.

Comment: This answer is very useful. Anyway I think that the data shouldn't be inside the code. I see two solutions: 1) if possible, read the constants from a file. 2) generate the code through a script which fill the data read from, for example, an xml.

Comment: It's certainly reasonable to read in the data from a file. JuMP's philosophy is to let the user decide how to structure the input instead of imposing certain file formats. For example, above you could fill `p` from a file using Julia's native I/O functions or the [LightXML.jl](https://github.com/lindahua/LightXML.jl) package.

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to search something about it.

Comment: @mlubin How would you continue for defining the objective ? I did try with `@objective(m, Max, sum(x[i]+p[i] for i in A))` but it doesn't work. Actually, Julia 0.5 gives me an error on the constrain statement as you wroted it: `LoadError: indexing Array{Pair{Symbol,Int64},1} with types Tuple{Symbol} is not supported`

Comment: I've corrected an error in the definition of `p`. The code should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't get the original answer of @mlubin working. Also, many examples around the web uses position-based indexing, that I don't feel so natural, so I rewritten the [trnsport.gms](http://www.gams.com/mccarl/trnsport.gms) example of the GAMS tutorial using dictionaries instead.. that feel much more close to gams/ampl "sets"..

```
#=
Transposition in JuMP of the basic transport model used in the GAMS tutorial

This problem finds a least cost shipping schedule that meets requirements at markets and supplies at factories.

- Original formulation: Dantzig, G B, Chapter 3.3. In Linear Programming and Extensions.
Princeton University Press, Princeton, New Jersey, 1963.
- Gams implementation: This formulation is described in        detail in:
Rosenthal, R E, Chapter 2: A GAMS Tutorial. In GAMS: A User's Guide.
The Scientific Press, Redwood City, California, 1988.
- JuMP implementation: Antonello Lobianco
=#

using JuMP, DataFrames

# Sets
plants  = ["seattle","san_diego"]          # canning plants
markets = ["new_york","chicago","topeka"]  # markets

# Parameters
a = Dict(              # capacity of plant i in cases
  "seattle"   => 350,
  "san_diego" => 600,
)
b = Dict(              # demand at market j in cases
  "new_york"  => 325,
  "chicago"   => 300,
  "topeka"    => 275,
)

#  distance in thousands of miles
d_table = wsv"""
plants     new_york  chicago  topeka
seattle    2.5       1.7      1.8
san_diego  2.5       1.8      1.4
"""
d = Dict( (r[:plants],m) => r[Symbol(m)] for r in       eachrow(d_table), m in markets)

f = 90 # freight in dollars per case per thousand miles

c = Dict() # transport cost in thousands of dollars per case ;
[ c[p,m] = f * d[p,m] / 1000 for p in plants, m in markets]

# Model declaration
trmodel = Model() # transport model

# Variables
@variables trmodel begin
    x[p in plants, m in markets] >= 0 # shipment quantities in cases
end

# Constraints
@constraints trmodel begin
    supply[p in plants],   # observe supply limit at plant p
        sum(x[p,m] for m in markets)  <=  a[p]
    demand[m in markets],  # satisfy demand at market m
        sum(x[p,m] for p in plants)  >=  b[m]
 end

# Objective
@objective trmodel Min begin
    sum(c[p,m]*x[p,m] for p in plants, m in markets)
end

print(trmodel)

status = solve(trmodel)

if status == :Optimal
    println("Objective value: ", getobjectivevalue(trmodel))
    println("Shipped quantities: ")
    println(getvalue(x))
    println("Shadow prices of supply:")
    [println("$p = $(getdual(supply[p]))") for p in plants]
    println("Shadow prices of demand:")
    [println("$m = $(getdual(demand[m]))") for m in markets]

else
    println("Model didn't solved")
    println(status)
end

# Expected result:
# obj= 153.675
#['seattle','new-york']   = 50
#['seattle','chicago']    = 300
#['seattle','topeka']     = 0
#['san-diego','new-york'] = 275
#['san-diego','chicago']  = 0
#['san-diego','topeka']   = 275
```

A much more commented version is available on my [related blog post](https://lobianco.org/antonello/personal:blog:2017:0203_jump_for_gams_users).